# Change alt+shift selection behavior in macvim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, selection, macvim

I'm browsing the web for a while to find a solution to my problem. First, I've already set up my vim with:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
    let macvim_hig_shift_movement = 1
endif
set selection=exclusive
```

But when I make a text selection in macvim with `alt+shift+left`, it emulates something like `visual+W` , but yet on Mac the default behavior is more similar as `visual+w` or `visual+e`. Does anyone know how to change this behavior?

Regards.

Comment: Haven't you found a solution for that issue? Me, I hate this MacVim behavior, too :).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tried this out but how about something like

```
vmap <S-C-Right> E
vmap <S-C-Left> B
```

etc.  Note that MacVim binds Shift+Alt+Arrow to Shift+Ctrl+Arrow, hence the "C" in these mappings.  You can see exactly what `macvim_hig_shift_movement` does by typing

```
tabe $VIM/gvimrc
```

and scroll to the bottom of that file (do not edit this file, it will get overwritten each time you update MacVim).